# Spring session concurrency tutorial

Tags: java, session, spring-mvc

I've started a Spring application in SpringSource Tool Suite and I want to add a session management feature in my web app, that is I want to prevent a user to login using the same account.

I've searched the net for tutorials and guides but failed to find an intuitive one for my knowledge in Spring. Could someone point me to a "tutorial for beginner" article.

Comment: What is "session concurrency"?

Comment: I want to prevent a user to login using the same account. More like session management. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Security provides this as described [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/session-mgmt.html#concurrent-sessions).

The typical Maven dependencies to use are:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

In the XML configuration, the declaration is typically something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
```

Then you can prefix the security elements with `sec:` such as

```
<sec:custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />
```

Or if you go off of the examples from the Spring Security documenation that I linked to, it prefixs the beans namesspace and leaves security as the default. Either way should serve the same purpose.

Comment: i'll give this a shot. do you have a link for maven dependencies of spring security?

Comment: I am having an error regarding the http namespace in the xml. Any idea how could I resolve this? I've been searching for the correct namespace but still unlucky.

Comment: @Oneb Did you miss out the Spring Security library?